# Widget not updating

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm trying to create a battery widget, but the textView that is supposed to show battery state isn't updating. It only changes if the phone is restarted. What is missing from the code?

**AndroidManifest:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".WidgetConfigurationActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MAppWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**AppWidgetProvider:**

```
    public class MAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    private String batteryLevel="init";

    @Override

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) 
{       
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  updateView(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{

    int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);  
    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);  
    int level = -1;  
    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;  
    batteryLevel = Integer.toString(level);  
    updateView(context); 
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

}

public void updateView(Context context) 
{
    RemoteViews thisViews = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    thisViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, batteryLevel);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            AnalogClockWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget,
            thisViews);
}
```

}

**Info:**

```
 <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
    android:configure="in.wptrafficanalyzer.appwidgetclockconfiguration.WidgetConfigurationActivity" 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use a service to update your widget because activity is in onPause state when you are outside application.

Secondly in service register an intent filter for receiving changes in battery status. And when its getting updated, notify appwidget.

You can also keep a variable in service to which widget will refer and set its level.